# how to replace string into react element in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to convert string into html(react elemtnt): `<a className="peoplelink" id="ether" onClick:{this.demoButton.bind(this)}>Ether</a> is the historian of the <a className="peoplelink" id="jaredites" onClick:{this.demoButton.bind(this)}>Jaredites</a>.`

> I have used
>
> > `dangerouslySetInnerHTML:`
>
> for convert string to HTML but it's not working properly

Comment: I wouldn't have much confidence in a method called `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Anyway, can you show your component?

Comment: let  description =  text.narration.description.replace(/{(.*?)\|(.*?)}/g, `<a className="peoplelink" id="$2" onClick={this.demoButton.bind(this)}>$1</a>`);                                                                       
                                                    description = React.createElement('span', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: description } });

Comment: @Héctor I have used " dangerouslySetInnerHTML " this way, but this is not converted in properly into react element

Comment: @Héctor, after using  " dangerouslySetInnerHTML " this the response is the browser is:-  <a classname="peoplelink" id="ether" onclick="{this.demoButton.bind(this)}">Ether</a>  and this is not correct

Comment: Never try to modify the DOM directly inside of React. Let React to do it for you.

Comment: @Dez  ok, can you tell me, please how I can I do in React js

Comment: I have a question, can you tell me please `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is convert string to html?

Answer (score 0):

What you pass as `__html` cannot use JSX syntax.

So use `class=` instead of `className=`, and `onclick="..."` (with a global function) instead of `onClick={...}`.

Comment: after using this I got same response like this :- <a classname="peoplelink" id="ether" onclick="{this.demoButton.bind(this)}">Ether</a>   here is the main problrm    onclick="{this.demoButton.bind(this)}" onclick event is in the the string

Comment: `<a className="peoplelink" onClick:{this.demoButton.bind(this)}>` is not really HTML. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: `React.createElement('span', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: description } });`  I am using this to convert string to html  **description** is my variable

Comment: @GouravKumar But `description` needs to be HTML, not JSX. I.e. something like `onclick="demoButtonHandler()`

Comment: But the issue is same   `<a class="peoplelink" id="ether" onclick="demoButton()">Ether</a>`   not get proper html

Comment: I have used  ` react-render-html ` plugin to get HTML, but here is another error occurs  ** Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type. **

Comment: Try without that plugin

Comment: I have tried, but the issue is same <a class="peoplelink" id="ether" onclick="demoButton()">Ether</a> not get proper html

Comment: and also found same error ` demoButton is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick` after click

Comment: You need to define a handler for the click, for example a `demoButton` function..